# How to bind nested observable collection value to listview

Tags: listview, uwp, observablecollection

I want to display all student names in a listview. I have done like below.But it shows an empty listview.

```
 public  class ClassRoomDetailsList
{
    public int ClassRoomID { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<StudentsList> StudentsArray { get; set; }
}

public class StudentsList
{
    public string StudentName{ get; set; }

}


public static ObservableCollection<ClassRoomDetailsList> _ClassRoomDetailsList = new ObservableCollection<ClassRoomDetailsList>();
//assigned values to observable collection here
list1.ItemsSource = AppGlobals._ClassRoomDetailsList;

 <ListView x:Name="list1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Height="500" Width="500"  Background="Violet" >
           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                     <Border Background="#b9fbc9" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding  StudentName}" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"    Foreground="Black"/>
                     </Border>
                     </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

I have checked that _ClassRoomDetailsList contains student name correctly. Yes it is. Then what is the issue for empty listview?

Comment: Well not sure how your UI needs to be. But if there are more class rooms with each room containing students, your list should only show the list for 1 room. Meaning the ItemsSource for the list should be something like ClassRoomDetailsLiist[0].StudentsList

Comment: there is only one class room

Comment: Your code states otherwise : ObservableCollection<ClassRoomDetailsList> _ClassRoomDetailsList > you created a List of Classrooms

Answer (score 0):

The `_ClassRoomDetailsList` is an `ObservableCollection<ClassRoomDetailsList>` object whose child items is `ClassRoomDetailsList` object, but your ListView want to bind the `StudentsList` object's `StudentName`, so your `ListView.ItemsSource` should be a  `ObservableCollection<StudentsList>` object.

Your binding in the ListView's DataTemplate should bind the **T** class object's properties in the ObservableCollection<**T**>. Here is a simple example base on your models.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ObservableCollection<StudentsList> studentsLists = new ObservableCollection<StudentsList>();
    studentsLists.Add(new StudentsList() { StudentName = "first student" });
    studentsLists.Add(new StudentsList() { StudentName = "second student" });
    studentsLists.Add(new StudentsList() { StudentName = "third student" });
    studentsLists.Add(new StudentsList() { StudentName = "fourth student" });
    studentsLists.Add(new StudentsList() { StudentName = "fifth student" });

    _ClassRoomDetailsList.StudentsArray = studentsLists;

    //assigned values to observable collection here
    list1.ItemsSource = _ClassRoomDetailsList.StudentsArray;
}
public ClassRoomDetailsList _ClassRoomDetailsList = new ClassRoomDetailsList();
```

More details about binding in uwp app, please see the topic [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart).